# Calculate the required return using an asset pricing model

Tags: risk, rate-of-return, assets

The current stock price of HHBA A is 101.00$. The last dividend payed
for HHBA A is 3.50$, and dividends are expected to grow at a constant rate of 6%.
Now i should calculate the required return using an asset pricing model. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [Dividend Discount Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividend_discount_model),

P = D / (r-g)

101.00=3.50/(r-0.06)

r = 0.0946535 = 9.47% = required return